# MySQL where condition unexpected behaviour

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I've the following simplified query which makes not much sense, but it well represents the problem:

```
SELECT `Work_Activity_Excl`
        , count(`Work_Activity_Excl`) as `Count1`
        , sum(if(`Work_Activity_Excl` = 0 ,1 ,0)) as `Count2`
FROM  `kpi_2023_mtt_detail`
WHERE `Work_Activity_Excl` = 0
group by `Work_Activity_Excl`;
```

In the "where" statement it filters out all except 0.
Still in the result I get lines for both 0 and 1 values:

[image]

Even more using the same filter in the condition of the IF statement of the `Count2` field works!

**How is this possible???**

This is the code producing the 'Work_Activity_Excl' column in the `kpi_2023_mtt_detail` view:

```
(case when (`b`.`Work_Activity` in ('Újrakábelezés','Self berendezés beüzemelés')) Then 1 else 0      end) as `Work_Activity_Excl`
```

I've MySQl8.32 server version and Workbench 8.028 both running on Windows.

I've tried replacing the view in the FROM statement with a union of simple 0 and 1 values and in that case it worked, but what do I miss in my statement producing the `Work_Activity_Excl` column?

Your help much appritiated.

Comment: The query should not produce more than one row. Something else is causing the behaviour. Can you show full code for the simplified view and some sample data.

Comment: Seems like you need to add `HAVING` for filtering your aggregated results

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/f3vt9cwZ  I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: slaakso - I fully agree, it should not produce more than one row, still it does. Actually my simplified query produces this result, and the sample data is just zeroes and ones from the view in the refferenced column. As I've written when I replace the source with a union of zero and one then the issue is gone too.

Comment: **lezhni** - Your hint was good. Actually the HAVING clause resolves the issue, still it does not explains the described behavior. In the original query I have other similar fields as conditions in the WHERE section, and they work as expected. Only this `Work_Activity_Excl` showing this issue.